# Program Prints the string in the wrong way. strcpy

Tags: c, c-strings, strcpy, strcat

After I put the input for name and surname (example: name:`Mario` surname:`Rossi`) As an output instead of getting `Mario Rossi` I get `ossi Rossi` but I can't understand why.

```c
int main() {
    char space[] = " ";
    char name[40], surname[40], space_name[40], space_surname[40];
    printf("what's your name");
    scanf("%[^\n]", &name);

    printf("Whats your surname");
    scanf(" %[^\n]", &surname);

    strcpy(space_surname, strcat(space, surname));
    strcat(name, space_surname);
    printf("%s", name);
}
```

Comment: `space` can only store a single character but you are copying much more into it, thus overwriting anything beyond. What you see is Undefined Behavior becuae of this.

Comment: @usr2564301 Thank you for answering, so basically a good way to solve this would be by putting space[N] with instead of N a big number? Could you tell me any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: Yes, that would be the standard way to handle it.  Otherwise, you can calculate all of the space you'll need and  use a Variable Length Array or you can dynamically allocate space with `malloc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strcat(dest, src)` will concatenate `src` onto `dest`. Your buffer `space` (length 1 not including null-terminator) isn't large enough to hold both. Also, your `space_surname` will overflow, as you're storing a size 1 string (`space`) *and* a size 40 string (`surname`) into a size 40 buffer. Increase it to at least size 41. Having a `space` string is also unnecessary, as `space` is character and can be set directly.

```c
space_surname[0] = ' ';
space_surname[1] = '\0';  // So you know where to concat to
strcat(space_surname, surname);
```

Note you run into the same issue with `name`. You're trying to store `name` (length 40), `space` (length 1), and `surname`(length 40) all into `name`. You need to create a new `full_name` variable of size 81 or greater and store into that.

Answer (score 3):

In your code, you first concatenate `surname` at the end of `space` with `strcat(space, surname)`, which has undefined behavior as `space` only has 2 elements, a space and a null terminator. Copying `surname` at the end corrupts the array `name`, which you observe as the `name` becomes `ossi`. This behavior is undefined, it happens this way on your architecture, but undefined behavior could have other consequences, including no visible effect or a computer crash.

Also note these remarks:

- you should tell `scanf()` the maximum number of characters to store into `name` and `surname` to avoid undefined behavior on overlong input.
- you should pass `name` instead of `&name`.
- you should test the return value of `scanf()` to avoid undefined behavior on invalid input, for example in case of unexpected end of file or an empty line for the first `scanf()`.
- you could define the arrays with sizes that make the behavior always defined.

For a cleaner approach, you would use 2 different arrays `firstname` and `surname` for the user input and construct the name into a third array `name` large enough for all cases:

```
strcpy(name, firstname);
strcat(name, " ");
strcat(name, surname);
```

or less readably:

```
strcat(strcat(strcpy(name, firstname), " "), surname);
```

Both of the above would needlessly iterate over the characters already copied into `name`. A much cleaner and safer solution is to use `snprinf()`:

```
snprintf(name, sizeof name, "%s %s", firstname, surname);
```

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char firstname[40]; /* up to 39 characters for the first name */
    char surname[40];   /* up to 39 characters for the last name */
    char name[80];      /* 39 chars + 1 space + 39 chars + 1 null terminator */

    printf("What is your name: ");
    if (scanf(" %39[^\n]", name) != 1)
        return 1;

    printf("What is your surname: ");
    if (scanf(" %39[^\n]", surname) != 1)
        return 1;

    /* simpler solution with `snprintf` */
    snprintf(name, sizeof name, "%s %s", firstname, surname);
    printf("%s\n", name);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @ChristianGibbons: hence my alternative *simpler solution* at the end of `main`.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons: I restructured my answer, yet I avoided the *efficiency* argument as 2 calls to `strcat` are probably still more *efficient* than the `snprintf` overhead.

Answer (score 1):

For starters these calls

```
scanf("%[^\n]", &name);

scanf(" %[^\n]", &surname);
```

are invalid. They must look at least like

```
scanf("%[^\n]", name);

scanf(" %[^\n]", surname);
```

The array `space` has no enough space to append the string stored in the array `surname`. So this call

```
strcpy(space_surname, strcat(space, surname));
```

is invalid.

It seems you mean

```
strcat( strcpy( space_surname, space ), surname);
```